# How to terminate a cv2.VideoCapture that is reading a gstreamer stream?

Tags: opencv, gstreamer

I'm streaming a video from a Raspberry Pi over a gstreamer pipeline. I read this stream on a desktop using OpenCV and gstreamer. Everything works great, except that the receiver does not know when the stream is finished.

The receiver code is essentially the same as in [convert gstreamer pipeline to opencv in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51539706/convert-gstreamer-pipeline-to-opencv-in-python)

My problem is if I don't quit the receiver by typing 'q', cap_receive.read() never seems to return False as its retval when the sender is done.

```
gst_str_simple = "udpsrc port=5000 ! application/x-rtp,encoding-name=H264,payload=96 ! rtph264depay ! avdec_h264 ! videoconvert ! appsink"

recv_cap = cv2.VideoCapture(gst_str_simple, cv2.CAP_GSTREAMER)

if not recv_cap.isOpened():
    print('VideoCapture not opened')
    exit(0)

while True:
    ret, frame = recv_cap.read()

    if not ret:
        print('empty frame')
        break

    cv2.imshow('receive', frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(1)&0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

recv_cap.release()
```

Can I write an empty frame at the sender to make this happen? Or any other way to make the receiver terminate automatically? Maybe a timeout?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if anyone looks at this, there was a simple solution I didn't think of earlier. I still don't know when the stream terminates by looking at the cv2 cap (recv_cap), but as I am using http requests between the Pi and the desktop anyway, once I receive a 'finish' message from the Pi, I just set a self.done = True in the main thread (note: the receiver is being run as a separate thread.), and exit the loop on this condition.

Answer (score 0):

Solution :

1. RTP or Media Inactivity Timers/Timeout 
   Create a Timer and terminate the call after some interval if you are not receiving any data from the network.
2. RTCP BYE - msg handling (https://www.freesoft.org/CIE/RFC/1889/32.htm)
   Make sure your Server is supporting RTCP protocol.